# BeautifulSoup - Use find_all() to find specific strings inside HTML

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Here is the current code that I have:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests

header = {'User-agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; de; rv:1.9.1.5) Gecko/20091102 Firefox/3.5.5'}

url  = requests.get("https://d1baseball.com/scores/?date=20170407&c=PKzxg", headers = header).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(url, 'html.parser')

boxscores = soup.find_all('a', text = 'Box Score')

for eachboxscore in boxscores:
    links = eachboxscore.get('href')
    print(links)
    url = requests.get(links, headers = header).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(url, 'html.parser')
    pbp = soup.find_all('a', text = {'Play-By-Play' or 'Play by Play' or 'Play By Play' or 'Play-by-Play'})
    print(pbp)
    for eachpbp in pbp:
        button = eachpbp.get('href')
        print(button)
```

I am not sure if I am implementing the logical operator 'or' correctly here or not. I want to be able to search 'a' tags in the html (for all the url's in the for loop - in this case there are 6 different links) and find the location of the Play-By-Play string to locate the respective link to the Play-By-Play data (note that sometimes the link to the Play-By-Play data is simply another url, whereas other times it may just redirect to another location on the same webpage such as: #play-by-play).

A quick follow-up question would then be, how to "click" this redirect link? Or would it be easier to append this to the end of the url that I am already located at?

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Hello. For your second question: you can "click" the link by calling `requests.get`. For your first question - i tried reading what you wrote, but have some difficulties in understanding what you are trying to ask.

Comment: Hi jmunsch. For my first question, essentially I am asking how to search for multiple different strings in a given 'a' tag. In other words, I know that this works for finding the string "Play-By-Play':

pbp = soup.find_all('a', text = 'Play-By-Play')

But what if I wanted to pass the other options as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
text=['Play-By-Play', 'Play by Play', 'Play By Play', 'Play-by-Play']
```

also see:

- https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-string-argument

The string argument With string you can search for strings instead of
tags. As with name and the keyword arguments, you can pass in a
string, a regular expression, a list, a function, or the value True.
Here are some examples:

> `soup.find_all(string="Elsie")`
>
> [u'Elsie']
>
> `soup.find_all(string=["Tillie", "Elsie", "Lacie"])`
>
> [u'Elsie', u'Lacie', u'Tillie']
>
> `soup.find_all(string=re.compile("Dormouse"))`
>    [u"The Dormouse's story",
>   u"The Dormouse's story"]
>
> `def is_the_only_string_within_a_tag(s):
>       """Return True if this string is the only child of its parent tag."""
>       return (s == s.parent.string)`
>
> `soup.find_all(string=is_the_only_string_within_a_tag)`
>
> [u"The Dormouse's story", u"The Dormouse's story", u'Elsie', u'Lacie', u'Tillie', u'...']

Although string is for finding strings, you can combine it with arguments that find tags: Beautiful Soup will find all tags whose .string matches your value for string. This code finds the  tags whose .string is “Elsie”:

> `soup.find_all("a", string="Elsie")`
>
> [Elsie]

The string argument is new in Beautiful Soup 4.4.0. In earlier versions it was called text:

> `soup.find_all("a", text="Elsie")`
>
> [Elsie]